# SwaggerUI response received event

Tags: javascript, swagger-ui

Is there an event to bind to, when a response arrived in SwaggerUI (after user clicks on 'Try it out' button ?

Want to do some extra processing on that response.

Otherwise will have to bind to swaggerUI DOM to monitor whether the response text area has been modified or not.

Answer (score 2):

responseInterceptor is available in SwaggerUi options to intercept the response.

```
new SwaggerUi({
  responseInterceptor: function respIntCb() { 
    var data = this; //data is passed in as this obj
    console.log(data)
  },
  ... //other constructor options
```

})